# Child function does not overwrite parent function

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance

i have a question regarding about inheritance between the child class and the parent class. Currently, my current `__Stack__push()` function in my child class `Stack3` is unable to overwrite the parent push function. As far as i know from my understanding, the child class is supposed to overwrite what has been defined in the parent class. However, in this case it is not happening.

```py
class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__list= []
 
    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.__list == []

    def size(self):
        return len(self.__list)

    def clear(self):
        self.__list.clear()

    def push(self, item):
        self.__list.append(item)

    def pop(self): # popTail
        if self.isEmpty():
            return None
        else:
            return self.__list.pop()

    def get(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            return None
        else:
            return self.__list[-1]

    def __str__(self):
        output = '<'
        for i in range( len(self.__list) ):
            item = self.__list[i]
            if i < len(self.__list)-1 :
                output += f'{str(item)}, '
            else:
                output += f'{str(item)}'
        output += '>'
        return output

class Stack3(Stack):
    def __init__(self,list):
        super().__init__()
        
    def push(self, item):
        super().push(item)
        self.__list = []
        self.__list.insert(0,item)
        
    def pop(self):
        super().pop()
        if self.isEmpty():
            return None
        else:
            return self.__list.pop(0)
    
# main programme    
s= Stack3(Stack())
print(s.pop())

for i in range(1,6):
    s.push(i)

print('Content of stack =',s)
print('Item at top=',s.get())
print('Size=', s.size())
while not s.isEmpty():
    print(s.pop())
    print(s)
```

The output was supposed to look something like this:

```py
None
Content of stack = <5, 4, 3, 2, 1>
Item at top= 5
Size= 5
5
<4, 3, 2, 1>
4
<3, 2, 1>
3
<2, 1>
2
<1>
1
<>
```

But my current one looks like this

```py
None
Content of stack = <1, 2, 3, 4, 5>
Item at top= 5
Size= 5
5
<1, 2, 3, 4>
```

and thereafter it gives me this error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-1eecf96bf9ca> in <module>
     66 print('Size=', s.size())
     67 while not s.isEmpty():
---> 68     print(s.pop())
     69     print(s)

<ipython-input-1-1eecf96bf9ca> in pop(self)
     53             return None
     54         else:
---> 55             return self.__list.pop(0)
     56 
     57 # main programme

IndexError: pop from empty list
```

Comment: it does not over ride because the name of the functions are different, the override will only occur when the names are the same.

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar Hi sir, even if i did change the functions to the same name, i still did not get my desired answer, and instead it failed to read the list. See the updated code.

Comment: that is going on because of an additional list that you have for some reason : it's caused by this line `return self.__list.pop(0)`. Please use a debugger to find these issues :)

Comment: your inheritance has already started to work, you can see that yourself by adding additional print statements inside the `Stack3` & `Stack`class and checking the output on the console. You'll need to resolve the additional list though, I did not understand it's purpose, hence, I haven't modified it

Comment: i intially wanted a additional list because i realise that `self.__list` is initially a private variable in the parent class and that i can't access it in the private class. Therefore, the additional list. But ye, i'll try to figure out an alternative!

Comment: you can access the parent's class `__list` variable using it's getter and setter methods, and that's one of the best practices. in your case, you will need to create them :)

Comment: I see. Got it! I will post the solution once i'm done! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after trials and errors and googling, here's my  answer. Please feel free to comment what can be modified!

```py
class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__list= []
 
    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.__list == []

    def size(self):
        return len(self.__list)

    def clear(self):
        self.__list.clear()

    def push(self, item):
        self.__list.append(item)

    def pop(self): # popTail
        if self.isEmpty():
            return None
        else:
            return self.__list.pop()

    def get(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            return None
        else:
            return self.__list[-1]

    def __str__(self):
        output = '<'
        for i in range( len(self.__list) ):
            item = self.__list[i]
            if i < len(self.__list)-1 :
                output += f'{str(item)}, '
            else:
                output += f'{str(item)}'
        output += '>'
        return output

class Stack3(Stack):
    def __init__(self,list):
        super().__init__()
        self.__list = []
        
    def push(self, item):
        super().push(item)
        self.__list.insert(0,item)
        
    def isEmpty(self):
        super().isEmpty()
        return self.__list == []
        
    def pop(self):
        super().pop()
        if self.isEmpty():
            return None
        else:
            return self.__list.pop(0)
        
    def __str__(self):
        output = '<'
        for i in range( len(self.__list) ):
            item = self.__list[i]
            if i < len(self.__list)-1 :
                output += f'{str(item)}, '
            else:
                output += f'{str(item)}'
        output += '>'
        return output
    
# main programme    
s= Stack3(Stack())
print(s.pop())

for i in range(1,6):
    s.push(i)

print('Content of stack =',s)
print('Item at top=',s.get())
print('Size=', s.size())
while not s.isEmpty():
    print(s.pop())
    print(s)
```